# iOS TBXML when should I add my object in my array?

Tags: ios, xml, parsing, object, tbxml

I'm building an object "Position" with the result of the XML extractions, it parses well
but I can't figure out when to add this object in an array. 
I want the object to be added after the following elements are extracted

I'm doing this:

```
- (void) traverseElement:(TBXMLElement *)element {
    position = [[Position alloc]init];
    NSString *cp;

    do {
        TBXMLAttribute * attribute = element->firstAttribute;
        BOOL foundElement = NO;

        while (attribute) {
            if ([[TBXML elementName:element] isEqualToString:@"referencecolis"]) {
                [idClient addObject: [TBXML textForElement:element]];
            };
            if ([[TBXML elementName:element] isEqualToString:@"idagencedepart"]) {
                [position setIdagencedepart:[TBXML textForElement:element]];
                NSLog(@"idagencedepart : %@",position.idagencedepart);
            };
            if ([[TBXML elementName:element] isEqualToString:@"idagencefinale"]) {
                [position setIdagencefinale:[TBXML textForElement:element]];
                NSLog(@"idagencedfinale : %@",[TBXML textForElement:element]);
            };
            if ([[TBXML elementName:element] isEqualToString:@"iddestinataire"]) {
                [position setIddestinataire:[TBXML textForElement:element]];
            };
            if ([[TBXML elementName:element] isEqualToString:@"idexpediteur"]) {
                [position setIddestinataire:[TBXML textForElement:element]];
                NSLog(@"idExpediteur : %@",[TBXML textForElement:element]);
            };
            if ([[TBXML elementName:element] isEqualToString:@"idTransporteurReexpedition"]) {
                [position setIdtransporteurreexpedition:[TBXML textForElement:element]];
                NSLog(@"idTransporteurReexpedition : %@",[TBXML textForElement:element]);
            };
            if ([[TBXML elementName:element] isEqualToString:@"typeadresse"] && [[TBXML textForElement:element]isEqualToString:@"1"] ) {
                [position setTypeAdresse:[TBXML textForElement:element]];
                NSLog(@"typeadresse : %@",[TBXML textForElement:element]);
            };
            if ([[TBXML elementName:element] isEqualToString:@"codepostal"]) {
                cp = [[TBXML textForElement:element] substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0,2)];
                [position setCodePostal:cp];
                NSLog(@"codePostal : %@",cp);
            };

            attribute = attribute->next;

            [arrayPositions addObject:position];
        }

        if (element->firstChild)
            [self traverseElement:element->firstChild];

    } while ((element = element->nextSibling));
```

I can't set a boolean to know if it's parsed since some elements are parsed two times.

Any help ?

Comment: you should addObject before the while loop.

Comment: if I do this, it adds empty objects in my array.

Comment: where did you initiate the arrayPositions NSMuatableArray?

Comment: in the ViewDidLoad method, it's a property. The problem is when to add the position object, when I add it inside the loop, it adds the same object in the arrayPositions